# Duplicate table data X times with unique primary key for testing

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to test some code but for that I need lots of data. my current table has not enough data, I want to duplicate the data but have unique primary key.

I can create it by using two table but was wondering if there is way to do it without creating two table.

Comment: Can you give an example how the table (especially the primary key) looks like ?

Comment: Is your primary key `auto_increment`?

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, as long as the `PRIMARY KEY` field is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, One (or more) [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert.asp) will copy the table rows back into itself.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO employees (name, department_id) 
  SELECT name, department_id FROM employees;
```

---

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE employees 
  (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(32), department_id INT);
INSERT INTO employees 
  (id, name, department_id) 
  VALUES (1, "Karen", 0), (2, "Joe", 1), (3, "Fred", 2), (4, "Sally", 2);

/*
id  name    department_id
1   Karen   0
2   Joe     1
3   Fred    2
4   Sally   2
*/

INSERT INTO employees (name, department_id) 
  SELECT name, department_id FROM employees;
```

...results in:

```
/*
id  name    department_id
1   Karen   0
2   Joe     1
3   Fred    2
4   Sally   2
5   Karen   0
6   Joe     1
7   Fred    2
8   Sally   2
*/
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3y759u6ph

---

This can be incorporated into a procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE copyEmployees(ii INT)

BEGIN

  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

  WHILE counter <= II DO
    INSERT INTO employees (name, department_id)
      SELECT name, department_id FROM employees;
    SET counter = counter + 1;
  END WHILE;
    
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL copyEmployees(3);
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3y759edxd

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross joins like this:

```
--MSSQL
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE AS A ,TABLE AS B,TABLE AS C,
TABLE AS D
```

Primary key shouldn't be a problem for this query